# How to restore a differential backup made under a different database name?

Tags: sql-server

I did a full backup of a database. Then I restored the database on another server, with a different name. Then I did a differential backup.

Now I want to restore the database using Management Studio. Both backups are checked by default, so I simply accept the default options. But then a message appears:

`You cannot select backup sets from different databases`

This is the same database, only the name is different. If I had made another full backup, right after restoring the database, I would have no problem. But I didn't. How to restore this differential backup?

Answer (score 0):

You can restore this differential backup using Transact-SQL. First analyze the contents of backups:

`RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM  DISK = 'L:\temp\1\pusta.bak'`

Then restore the backups in 2 steps:

```
RESTORE DATABASE pusta FROM DISK = 'L:\temp\1\spplus_pusta.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, NORECOVERY
GO
RESTORE DATABASE pusta FROM DISK = 'L:\temp\1\spplus_pusta.bak' WITH  FILE = 2, RECOVERY
GO
```

I found this answer on a Russian forum [sql.ru](http://www.sql.ru/forum/401006/problemy-pri-vosstanovlenii-bazy-sql-2005#3837674), thank you, **pr0ger**.